# How to show a nodejs function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Im trying to sort movies by rating, doing it in node work fine, same case when I do with angular only.

My problem is when i try to print in angular the function made on Node.
I know, i need to use $http.get but i cant understand how to use it.

Here is my nodejs function writed in my server.js

```html
app.get('/movie/rate=:imdbRating', function (req, res) {
 fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "server/data/list.json", function (err, data) {
  movies = JSON.parse( data );
  var movieByRate = [];
  for(var i=0; i<movies.length;i++){
  if (movies[i].imdbRating===parseInt(req.params.imdbRating)){
   movieById.push(movies[i]);
   }
  }
 res.end( JSON.stringify(movieByRate));
 });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "i try to print in angular the function made on Node" this does not make sense to me... could you rephrase your question ?

Comment: use angular service to hit the end points. Inject the angular service in your controller and then display on UI

Comment: `app.get` is client side (frontend), `fs.readFile` is backend. What you are trying to do doesn't make sense. Use AJAX requests instead.